# Android - Show image from resource drawable

Tags: android, image, android-intent, resources

I'm new at Android apps and I'm working on a project started by a friend of mine. The code below is from a class that loads a view that has a small image with some text around it.

I want the image to appear fullscreen (on the standard Android image viewer) when I click on the thumbnail.
I tried several different solutions, and none of them worked.

This example throws the following exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(13768): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=android.resource://com.app.mid/2130837533 typ=image/png }
```

```java
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_n1);

    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(imageResource);

    img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.app.mid/" + R.drawable.p_page_11_image_0001), "image/png");
            startActivity(intent);              
        }
    });        
}
```

The images are inside the drawable folder (..\res\drawable-xhdpi). I'm using Eclipse ADT and I configured it to run on my Galaxy Nexus.

Again, I tried several solutions with no luck. Any thoughts?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Intent.ACTION_VIEW instead of android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(yourUri, "image/png");
startActivity(intent);
```